# Is it possible to force the Unity launcher to hide? Or to toggle hide/unhide with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: unity, launcher

I would like to manually control when the launcher is shown or hidden. Is it possible? There is no option to "never show launcher", nor have I found a way to force the launcher to hide.

Comment: So it seems this is not possible. I opened a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/894384), let's see what the Unity team will make out of it. Thanks everybody for your answers.

Comment: The above question is quite an old question from 2011 but a similar question and answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/292542/keyboard-shortcut-to-toggle-auto-hide-unity-launcher will probably be useful to anyone looking at this. There's a good answer starting with: "One way to do it simply is to create a custom shortcut."

Answer (score 2):

If the launcher is set to auto-hide, with <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> (mostly <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>) you can make the launcher show again. Havent found a way to hide the launcher through a shortcut though.

Answer (score 2):

I use unity2d and i made this script to toogle the launcher :

```
#!/bin/sh
var=$(gsettings get com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher hide-mode)
if [ "$var" = 0 ]
then
    exec gsettings set com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher hide-mode 2
else
    exec gsettings set com.canonical.Unity2d.Launcher hide-mode 0
fi
```

after you can set a shortcut who launch this script

Comment: Any idea if it works with Unity 3D?

Comment: @sup Have a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/292542/keyboard-shortcut-to-toggle-auto-hide-unity-launcher/292555?noredirect=1#292555) for the equivalent for unity 3D

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it to hide automatically when not used. Launch the CompizConfig Settings Manager (package compizconfig-settings-manager), find the Ubuntu Unity Plugin there, and change the Hide Launcher setting to "Autohide".

Comment: Yeah, I know, the trouble is in "automatically". I would like to be able to trigger hide/unhide manually (via a shortcut, preferably)

Answer (score -1):

I use Cairo-Dock (not without its own set of problems) as it is far superior to the Unity launcher. What I have done for the moment is use compizconfig settings manager to enable auto-hide, in combination with the reveal mode set to 'None'. Now instead of popping up when I navigate to the edge of the screen it only pops up (annoyingly) when using 'find'.

Of course, I really would really rather just disable the launcher altogether. And compiz too, but gnome unfortunately does not support transparencies without compiz. And Unity apparently just doesn't work without the horrible launcher.

Comment: The person isn't asking for an alternative to Unity.

Comment: Neither am I. Read the post.

Comment: @Ryan, no you are suggesting to switch to cario-dock.

Comment: Perhaps I stated it poorly, but I only described to the parent poster how I hid the Unity launcher and why. Again I say to you, actually _read_ my post, and maybe the parent poster's as well. We may have different end goals but the solution is the same.

Comment: Ryan: thanks, but that would be too cumbersome for me though.

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention that compizconfig can be used to show the launcher on key press. I have it set this way it works fine.

Comment: Doesn't toggle though, I have to hold one of my combo keys down while I navigate...

Comment: @Ryan I DID read your post. Your post goes on about cario-dock and then you just say that you would disable the launcher if you could. That is NOT a solution.