# Is there a way to hide & reveal the launcher at will with the press of a key? 

Tags: unity, launcher, autohide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to force the Unity launcher to hide? Or to toggle hide/unhide with a keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45673/is-it-possible-to-force-the-unity-launcher-to-hide-or-to-toggle-hide-unhide-wit)

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with the default Unity desktop environment.

I'm aware of all the keyboard shortcuts that relate to the launcher as well as the possible tweaks using Ubuntu Tweak Tool, Unsettings, MyUnity.

What I'd like to know is this: Is there a way to hide & reveal the launcher at will with the press of a key? Example given, press Key A, launcher hides, press Key A again and launcher is revealed until I press the A Key once more and so forth.

The autohide function won't do because I want the launcher to stay visible once revealed.